# Django freezer app - Checking a time delta

Tags: python, django, model, timedelta

I am working on a project for organizing a freezer.
Therefore I added a model called 'ShoppingItem'. It has an 'best before' date.
Now I want to check three things via a function:

Is the food expired?
Is the food fine?
Or is the food 'critical' (3 days before expiring)

This is my whole models.py
It includes the model itself and two functions.

[model ShoppingItem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHbop.png)

[function 'expired'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oeBT.png)

I tried on the expired function but in the admin interface it always only shows 'fine' or 'expired'

[admin interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIvWk.png)

**SOLUTION:**

This is the final solution to my problem. Now it works :-)
[image: SOLUTION]

Comment: Can you clarify what is wrong with the proposed code?

Comment: I want products that are 3 (or less) days before expiring to show as 'critical'.
Thus the user knows 'okay I need to consume the food it will be expired soon'
But the function 'expired' only returns 'fine' or 'expired'. My Elif does not catch the desired timedelta.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your elif condition.
You passed

```
def expired(self):
    if self.best_before_date > datetime.date.today():
        return 'fine'
    elif self.best_before_date >= datetime.date.today() and
            self.best_before_date >= datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=3):
        return 'critical'
    else:
        return 'expired'
```

But correct is `self.best_before_date <= datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=3)` because you need date more than today, but less or equal than today + 3 days.

Comment: I changed my code after the 'AND' operator to your suggestion. But in the admin area of django it still only shows 'fine' or 'expired'.

Comment: show what in self.best_before_date and what in datetime.date.today() please

Comment: I posted the solution on top of my question in case you are curious.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the correct logic:

```py
def expired(self):
    three_days_before = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=3)
    if self.best_before_date < three_days_before:
        return 'fine'
    elif three_days_before <= self.best_before_date <= datetime.date.today():
        return 'critical'
    # after expiration date
    else:
        return 'expired'
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to change your code a little but now it works.
I posted the end result in my question on top.